# Getting initial data pattern in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to understand the pattern to use in Xamarin Forms when a page gets its initial data from a web API.

The page is tied to a `ViewModel`. Let's use this simple example:

```
public class DataFeedViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   public DateFeedViewModel()
   {
       Title = "My Feed";
   }

   public List<FeedItem> Feed { get; set; }

}
```

The `DataFeedViewModel` is bound to the page:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingContext = new DataFeedViewModel();
}
```

As I understand it, I use the `OnAppearing()` method to fetch my initial set of data from the backend API:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    var result = await _myApiService.GetFeed();
    // What's next? Do I simply do the following?
    // new DataFeedViewModel
    // {
    //     Feed = result
    // }
}
```

Also a second but very important question is whether this pattern is the recommended approach.

As I learn about Xamarin and .NET Maui, I understand, the trend is to go from an event driven model to a more `MVVM` command driven approach.

I'm a bit confused about how to use a `ViewModel` to tap into these life cycle methods such as `OnAppearing()`.

Comment: We don't see the full picture of your code, it is a bit broad question, but you probably want to update your Feed list, which is probably bound in your xaml, also think about replacing List with an Observable collection which implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: "recommended" is a matter of opinion.  You might try adding an `Init` method to your VM that will call `GetFeed`, instead of having the page do it.

Comment: @Jason That makes sense. Where can I find some code samples for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an `Init` method on your VM

```
public class DataFeedViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   public DateFeedViewModel()
   {
       Title = "My Feed";
   }

   public List<FeedItem> Feed { get; set; }

   public async void Init()
   {
       Feed = await _myApiService.GetFeed();
   }
}
```

and then have your page call it

```
private DataFeedViewModel VM { get; set; }

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingContext = VM = new DataFeedViewModel();
}

protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    await VM.Init();
}
```